# Display images from multi directories / folders

Tags: php

i want to display images from multi directories here the structure of my folders:

1. Karyawan

   - BCS=*John.jpg*
   - KM=*Ahmad.jpg*
   - MBR=*Laura.jpg*
2. Karyawan_Subcont

   - BMC
   - PAMA
   - PBU

And this my code

```
<?php
    $result = mysql_query("select * from gambar order by id ASC limit $posisi,$batas"); 
    while ($fetch_tampil = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        if($result['perusahaan'] == 'BCS') {
            $result ="../database_foto_karyawan/foto_karyawan/BCS/";
        } elseif($result['perusahaan'] == 'KM') {
            $result ="../database_foto_karyawan/foto_karyawan/KM/";
        } elseif($result['perusahaan'] == 'MBR') {
            $result ="../database_foto_karyawan/foto_karyawan/MBR/";
        } elseif($result['perusahaan'] == 'BMC') {
            $result ="../database_foto_karyawan/foto_karyawan_subcont/BMC/";
        } elseif($result['perusahaan'] == 'PAMA') {
            $result ="../database_foto_karyawan/foto_karyawan_subcont/PAMA/";
        } elseif($result['perusahaan'] == 'PBU') {
            $result = "../database_foto_karyawan/foto_karyawan_subcont/PBU/";
        }    
?>
```

Maybe anyone can help me..thanks in advance

Comment: At the time of upload if you save the path of uploaded image too in one column then this much if else and nasty code is not needed. Just use that path in `<img src=` and it's done

Comment: I don't see a question here..

Comment: @Anant i use the path in <img src="/<?echo $row['gambar'];?>" but it won't show up

Comment: what is there in `$row['gambar'];`?

Comment: $gambar is the path of uploaded image save in dbase @Anant

Answer (score 1):

save total path in your database.if you are display this images in subdirectories yous this:

```
<img src="/your_website_title/path_save_in_database">
```

for example supose we are in Karyawan_Subcont/BCM subdirectory and we want to show Jhon.jpg

```
 <img src="/your_website_title/Karyawan/BCS/Jhon.jpg">
```

using php

```
<img src="/<?php echo $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] ?>/Karyawan/BCS/Jhon.jpg">
```

Comment: is that possible i put the  images folders not in my website title folders but both still in localhost ?i mean i got 1 folder named project inside project i've got 2 folders my website and my folders images

Comment: yes it's posible...your website_name i mean:  for example----your url is localhost/website_name/folder/file.php   so use code in my answer with your website_name you have.